# phpbb deleted all inactive users now can't login

Tags: phpbb3

I had 45K inactive users on my phpbb3 board.
Went on to delete them from mysql (erased all that had user_new=1).
Now I can't login, and the board shows no forums.

No idea how to get all the forums and the login back without resorting to restore the database.
It would be good to know why this happen if I only erased inactive users.

Comment: Do you have a backup of mysql? I would expect a site with that volume of users to have some backup routine?

Comment: Well, I happen to have it, of course. And I can get it back with all 45K users too. 
It seems my "get all back"  was not precise.  I edited it.
What I meant with "all back" is all the forums back.
And maybe in the process, learn WHY the thing drop dead if I deleted INACTIVE users. Couldn't find the answer in the phpbb docs so far. Thanks.

Comment: You could restore from the backup database. Another alternative possibly dependant on configuration and version would be point in time recovery: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

Comment: Thanks wayne, But you keep giving me database related answers, and I am asking about phpbb logic for not showing me the forums if I delete INACTIVE users. maybe has to do with the forums being populated with posts from those users... Anyways, I am trying to avoid to solve the issue rolling back mysql.

Comment: you should clarify your question so it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer.
[This link](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1987055#p12060675) has the mysql statement to bring things back.

So, for what it worth, whatever you do, don't delete the anonymous user from the database...